# copy_to_user struct with dynamic array

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

This is the form of the struct

```
struct mySt{
   int *list;
   int counter;
}
```

This is the kernel space side

```
struct mySt = newSt;

copy_to_user((struct mySt*) arg, newSt, sizeof(struct mySt));
```

A kmalloc has been performed on the *list between the creation of the struct and the copy_to_user

This is the user space side

```
ioctl(fd, LIST, &newst);
```

The fd is the variable the has performed the open().
The LIST is the name of the ioctl operation.

On the user side i get the counter just fine but i cant find a way to pass the array *list.

I would like to know a good way to pass a struct with a dynamic array from kernel space to user space.

Comment: Sooo 1. user space does ioctl to query the needed size. 2. User space allocates the size 3. second ioctl where data is transferred to the buffer allocated in step 2.

Comment: User space could fill in `newst` before the ioctl, setting `newst.list` to point to buffer of `int`s buffer, and setting `newst.counter` to maximum number of `int`s that will fit in the buffer. Kernel code needs to verify that the array of `int`s that it wants to return will fit in the user-supplied buffer (and take some appropriate action if it doesn't fit), and use `copy_to_user` to copy to the user's buffer of `int`s. It should not replace the `list` pointer value in the `struct mySt` that is copied back to the user.